# Achieving VTOL by blowing wind directly in the wings?

Tags: physics, engineering, aircraft, flying-machines

In my story I pictured an aircraft that possess ducted wings that achieve lift by having air blown directly at them, originally by fans, then "bladeless" dyson thrusters that would have been the ducts themselves, as I believed it would be more silent (it wouldn't) and have now settled for some sort of Ionic wind propulsion, but the method of propulsion is irrelevant I think, the thing is that having fixed position ducted wings would reduce the number of moving parts and consequently the wear and tear.

Does this concept make sense physically speaking? I got inspired by videos of airplanes tryng to land on high winds and appearing to be suspended in the air.

Comment: Uh, I'm sorry to break a dream, but Dyson-like bladeless fans are... Well, [often far from silent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dS0oFmzU06g) ^^' (+some other French consumer magasine for reference) . Since it blows air through slits with a much smaller fan (because [there is still a fan, just hidden in the base, and no coriolis effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFCFe38EIfE&t=472s)), it tends to get noiser than other, non-bladeless fans for the same wind output. But you can still use them if you wish, they're indeed cool looking and that's what matters to most :)!

Comment: Not a complete answer, but there's no way you'd produce more lift from airflow directly mostly over the wings (most of the force directed horizontally) than you would from directing force in opposition to the direction you wish to move (normal thrusters).  So you're better off aiming your Dyson thrusters directly at the ground than faffing around with trying to generate lift with an airfoil.

Comment: VTC: (a) You don't need our permission to use an idea. (b) We don't answer questions about the Real World unless it's in a worldbuilding context (whether or not something could work in the Real World isn't a worldbuilding question, it's an engineering question). In your world, the idea works by definition and in fiction the idea is suitable for suspension-of-disbelief. (c) If you're asking an [tag:internal-consistency] question, you need to explain your world rules to test for consistency.

Comment: @JBH I have to disagree on the off-topic here : People ask a lot about things heavily related to real-world, like planet physics, [vehicles](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/215713/80336) or [crossing ravines using real-world physics only means](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/209717/80336). There's enough of genuine worldbuilding context (I mean, a sand submarine/flying ship/hydrofoil boat hybrid would never exist in real-world). Others close reasons still have to be checked (looking at clarity from my side), but it's not off-topic.

Comment: @Tortliena The OP isn't asking for help designing a technology for their world (on-topic), they're presenting an answer and asking if it's realistic in the Real World (off-topic). If Paulo wants help designing his craft, I'm all for it. If all he's looking for is our blessing as engineers, I believe that's off-topic per the [help]. (And you have my opinion on the matter. You're welcome, as usual, to the last word, but I'm not getting into a debate. My VTC per my interpretation of the rules stands. Paulo isn't asking a worldbuilding question.)

Comment: If we frame the question as "is this believable," then I think it might be appropriate. I'd call this a poor design for a hard science fiction book, but a fun machine for high adventure. Anyone with an understanding of laminar flows would say "air just doesn't work that way," but it sounds like it might work.

Comment: @JBH Do you have a precise help-center quote? I ask because your current analysis of the rules contradicts a bit with the internal-consistency/hard-science/science-based tags you rewrote yourself 2 months ago : "*[To ask questions concerning the reality, realism, ..., etc. of an idea, concept, or rule vs. the Real World, users should use the science-based or hard-science tags.*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/internal-consistency/info)". So... I can't understand ^^". (P.S. : You don't need to tell you won't answer. As writers says : Do it, don't tell you do it ;) ).

Comment: I suspect you are better off just shooting the air straight downwards to push your craft upwards.

Comment: I think in the real world the Dyson like fans would not work, but since it would be hard to get enough thrust, or mass flow if you want to look at it that way, but as a concept of how something might look, with some super-tech it could still fit in your world building concept.  I think they are also likely to be loud. when scaled to the size, to lift aircraft.

Comment: Don't see why this should be closed. There are lots of questions on here about whether a concept is realistic. Isn't that what the 'reality-check' tag is for? Just because the answer is "yes" doesn't make it any less a Worldbuilding question. (Often the answer is "yes" *and* the person answering gives a real-life example!)

Comment: @Daron - I understood it that an external source would blow the wind rather than the craft itself. Although then would would think it better to blow the air up from underneath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, there is a vehicle in existence that blows air out from the edge to lift itself up--the [Avro Aerocar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Canada_VZ-9_Avrocar). It doesn't use coriolis effect though, it used the [Coandă effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coand%C4%83_effect) instead.

[image: Avro Aerocar]

<sup>*The Avro Canada VZ-9 Avrocar 58-7055 on its rollout. Developed in the late 1950s, the aircraft exploited the Coandă effect to provide lift and thrust from a single 124-blade turborotor blowing exhaust out of the rim of the 18 ft (5.5 meters) disk. Picture [from Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Colour_avrocar_59.jpg), said to be in the public domain.*</sup>